# solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Prove that this problem has a unique solution, and calculate the solution
$$y' = (1 + y) x , y(0) = -1$$

My solution is: $f(x,y)=(1+y)x$ is $\mathcal{C}^1$ so the Cauchy-Lipchitz theorem says: the problem admits a unique solution on an open intervall $J$
we remark that $y = -1$ is a solution for this problem, so bu unicity, the solution of this problème is $y=1$ on $\mathbb{R}.$

My problem is, if we calculate the solution conventionally, we have $$\int_{-1}^y \dfrac{1}{1+s} ds = \int_0^x s ds$$
I can not get the solution
Help me please

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at $y=-1$, you're not allowed to divide by $1+y$.
Thus $y^\prime = (1+y)x$ means that either $1+y=0$ or $\frac{y^\prime}{1+y} = x$.

If you really insist on having a heuristic argument consider:
$$\ln|1+y| = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y} = \int x\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}x^2+c,$$
thus $y = -1\pm e^ce^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}$. Your solution is now given by picking $c=-\infty$, so that $e^c=0$.

Comment: we have $y(0)=-1$ not $y(0)=1$

Comment: Sorry, typo. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Okay, so the solution of the problem is $y(x)=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$ Just a question: why  the fact that the constant must be infinite for had a solution that satisfies the intial conditions  is an argument to say that the solution is $y=-1$?

Comment: It isn't. It's a heuristic. You really need to check the solution to see if it actually solves the differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

$-1$ is a constant solution of the equation, so we only need to solve the homogeneous equation and find solutions satisfying $y(0) = 0$. Then this equation is $y' = x y$ so $(\ln y)' = x$ and solutions are of the form $y(x) = C \exp(\frac{x^2}{2})$, we get $y(0) = C = 0$. So the only solution with condition $y(0) = -1$ is indeed $-1$.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. We have $\int \dfrac{y'}{y+1} dy = \int x dx$ then $\ln|1 + y| = \dfrac{x^2}{2} + c$ then $|1+y| = e^c e^{\dfrac{x^2}{c}}$ and how we can remove the absolute value?

Comment: Since the unique solution of the IVP is guaranteed by the basic existence-uniqueness theorem for IVPs (for first-order eqns.) and since $y=-1$ solves the problem, it is the only solution you are seeking.

Comment: If you know the problem has a unique solution and you have this solution at hand, then looking for another solution is meaningless. In such a case You will always meet some absurdities such as not finding the constant appering in the solution (sorry in nothing)